# Add version information to existing unversioned file

Tags: versioning, backwards-compatibility, forward-compatibility

I know I've seen this asked and answered in great detail before, but I can't find it for the life of me, so I'll ask again.

I've inherited some legacy code, and as is often the case with legacy code, it was not written with forward-compatibility in mind. The application makes use of a data file for storing collected data on which calculations are performed. I want to add a versioning system to this data file in such a way that, in the future, the application can simply check the version information and handle the file appropriately.

What are the best practices for maintaining backwards-compatibility while adding forward-compatibility features to a data file?